# Find the differences between nested dictionaries which contain lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to extract the differences between two nested dictionaries and I want the result to include the full dictionary keypath. I have installed Python2.7 and DeepDiff, which appears to be the best option for what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to determine how to change the output of DeepDiff so it provides the full dictionary path and values rather than a set which I cannot index. Is there a better way to alter the output (rather than converting the output back to a dictionary)?

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
knownAPs = {'WLC1': {'10.1.1.1': {'72.6': ['AP22', 'city'], '55.1': ['AP102', 'office']}}, 'WLC2': {'10.1.1.2': {}}}
discoveredAPs = {'WLC1': {'10.1.1.1': {}}, 'WLC2': {'10.1.1.2': {}}}
ddiff = DeepDiff(knownAPs, discoveredAPs)
if 'dic_item_added' in ddiff.keys():
    print('Item added to known: ' + str((ddiff['dic_item_added'])))
if 'dic_item_removed' in ddiff.keys():
    DisAssociatedAPs = (list(list(ddiff['dic_item_removed'])))
    for i in DisAssociatedAPs:
        fullkeypath = (str(i).strip('root'))
        ControllerName = (fullkeypath[0])
        ControllerIP = (fullkeypath[1])
        AccessPointIndex = (fullkeypath[2])
        print('AP: ' + str(knownAPs + fullkeypath) + ' on controller: ' + str(ControllerName) + ' was removed from the known database')
if 'values_changed' in ddiff.keys():
    print('Item changed: ' + str((ddiff['values_changed'])))
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/xxx/testdic4.py", line 15, in <module>
    print('AP: ' + str(knownAPs + fullkeypath) + ' on controller: ' + str(ControllerName) + ' was removed from the known database')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Preferred Output

```
AP: ['AP22', 'city'] on controller: ['WLC1'] was removed from the known database
AP: ['AP102', 'office'] on controller: ['WLC1'] was removed from the known database
```

Comment: Right now you don't have *any* output, expected or otherwise, because you are trying to add a dict and a string (somewhere you couldn't be bothered to identify).

Comment: Hi Scott. From the error I can see that I cannot concatenate a dictionary and string. I am a novice programmer and hence why I am asking for guidance on how to do this. Is there another forum I should use for asking basic questions?

Comment: @zeepi When you post code that gets an error, you should provide the traceback so we can easily see what line of code caused the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is exactly what the traceback tells you: you are trying to add a dictionary to a string, which is of course not what you want. Specifically, when you add `knownAPs` (type `dict`) to `fullkeypath` (type `str`) you get an error, because `dict` doesn't know how to add itself to a `str`.

But that doesn't answer your more general question of how to output the diffs in a way you want. Try this:

```
diffs = deepdiff.DeepDiff(knownAPs, discoveredAPs)

def get_value_from_string(d, s):
    s = list(filter(None, (piece[2:-1] for piece in s.split(']'))))

    for piece in s:
        d = d[piece]
    return d


if 'dic_item_removed' in diffs:
    for item in diffs['dic_item_removed']:
        item = item.strip('root')
        base = item[2:item.find(']') - 1]
        print('AP:', get_value_from_string(knownAPs, item), 
            'on controller: \'' + base + '\' was removed from the known '
            'database')
```

Comment: Understood. So what is the best way to convert the fullkeypath string into a dictionary key (e.g. knownAPs['WLC1']['10.1.1.1']['72.6'])?

Comment: @zeepi I have updated my answer to better answer that question

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted :) Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I will take some time to figure out how you have done this.

Comment: @zeepi Great! If it helped you out, please upvote and accept my answer (: